log statement not printing anything in flow playground
I am trying to run below code on flow playground in scripts code runs no error but it is not printing anything in log section. this is occurring for past few month before that i was able to print.
pub fun main(){
  log("HelloWorld")
}

I am expecting Result > "HelloWorld" output but instead I am getting this Result > ().


Flow Playground has been updated to support Cadence 1.0
and it also includes numerous fixes
try to open this project and run this script:
access(all) fun main(){
  log("HelloWorld")
}

